# need to call a function with the argument the group_by variable

Tags: r

I am exploring data and concluded a function would be useful.  The attached code uses the iris dataset and there are 4 attempts at creating a usable function but each one gives the error that the group_by variable was not found.

Here's the code.  The first segment is just plain code that works.  The next 4 are failed functions.

```
#  dplyr group by programically
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
dtbl %>% group_by(Species) %>%
     mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
     summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
                    mean(Sepal.Width))


datafun <- function(groupbyvar)
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar)
dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
dtbl %>% group_by_(groupbyvar) %>%
     mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
     summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
                    mean(Sepal.Width))

bb <- datafun("Species")

datafun <- function(groupbyvar)
     library(dplyr)
data(iris)
groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar)
dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
dtbl %>% group_by_("groupbyvar") %>%
     mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
     summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
                    mean(Sepal.Width))

bb <- datafun("Species")


datafun <- function(groupbyvar)
     library(dplyr)
data(iris)
groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar)
dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
dtbl %>% group_by(groupbyvar) %>%
     mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
     summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
                    mean(Sepal.Width))

bb <- datafun("Species")

datafun <- function(groupbyvar)
     library(dplyr)
data(iris)
groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar)
dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
dtbl %>% group_by("groupbyvar") %>%
     mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
     summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
                    mean(Sepal.Width))

bb <- datafun("Species")

and the console output

> #  dplyr group by programically
> library(dplyr)
> data(iris)
> dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
> dtbl %>% group_by(Species) %>%
+      mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
+      summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
+                     mean(Sepal.Width))
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

     Species MeanSepalLenght MeanSepalWidth
      (fctr)           (dbl)          (dbl)
1     setosa           5.006          3.428
2 versicolor           5.936          2.770
3  virginica           6.588          2.974
> 
> 
> datafun <- function(groupbyvar)
+ library(dplyr)
> data(iris)
> groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar)
Error: object 'groupbyvar' not found
> dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
> dtbl %>% group_by_(groupbyvar) %>%
+      mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
+      summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
+                     mean(Sepal.Width))
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in as.lazy_dots(list(...)) : object 'groupbyvar' not found 
12 as.lazy_dots(list(...)) 
11 lazyeval::all_dots(.dots, ...) 
10 group_by_prepare(.data, ..., .dots = .dots, add = add) 
9 group_by_.data.frame(., groupbyvar) 
8 group_by_(., groupbyvar) 
7 function_list[[i]](value) 
6 freduce(value, `_function_list`) 
5 `_fseq`(`_lhs`) 
4 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
3 eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
2 withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)) 
1 dtbl %>% group_by_(groupbyvar) %>% mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * 
    Sepal.Width) %>% summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), 
    MeanSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)) 
> 
> bb <- datafun("Species")
> 
> datafun <- function(groupbyvar)
+      library(dplyr)
> data(iris)
> groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar)
Error: object 'groupbyvar' not found
> dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
> dtbl %>% group_by_("groupbyvar") %>%
+      mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
+      summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
+                     mean(Sepal.Width))
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error: unknown column 'groupbyvar' 
12 stop(structure(list(message = "unknown column 'groupbyvar'", 
    call = NULL, cppstack = NULL), .Names = c("message", "call", 
"cppstack"), class = c("Rcpp::exception", "C++Error", "error", 
"condition"))) 
11 grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) 
10 grouped_df(groups$data, groups$groups) 
9 group_by_.data.frame(., "groupbyvar") 
8 group_by_(., "groupbyvar") 
7 function_list[[i]](value) 
6 freduce(value, `_function_list`) 
5 `_fseq`(`_lhs`) 
4 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
3 eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
2 withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)) 
1 dtbl %>% group_by_("groupbyvar") %>% mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * 
    Sepal.Width) %>% summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), 
    MeanSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)) 
> 
> bb <- datafun("Species")
> 
> 
> datafun <- function(groupbyvar)
+      library(dplyr)
> data(iris)
> groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar)
Error: object 'groupbyvar' not found
> dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
> dtbl %>% group_by(groupbyvar) %>%
+      mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
+      summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
+                     mean(Sepal.Width))
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error: unknown column 'groupbyvar' 
13 stop(structure(list(message = "unknown column 'groupbyvar'", 
    call = NULL, cppstack = NULL), .Names = c("message", "call", 
"cppstack"), class = c("Rcpp::exception", "C++Error", "error", 
"condition"))) 
12 grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) 
11 grouped_df(groups$data, groups$groups) 
10 group_by_.data.frame(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...), 
    add = add) 
9 group_by_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...), add = add) 
8 group_by(., groupbyvar) 
7 function_list[[i]](value) 
6 freduce(value, `_function_list`) 
5 `_fseq`(`_lhs`) 
4 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
3 eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
2 withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)) 
1 dtbl %>% group_by(groupbyvar) %>% mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * 
    Sepal.Width) %>% summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), 
    MeanSepalWidth = mean(Sepal.Width)) 
> 
> bb <- datafun("Species")
> 
> datafun <- function(groupbyvar)
+      library(dplyr)
> data(iris)
> groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar)
Error: object 'groupbyvar' not found
> dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
> dtbl %>% group_by("groupbyvar") %>%
+      mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
+      summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
+                     mean(Sepal.Width))
Source: local data frame [1 x 3]

  "groupbyvar" MeanSepalLenght MeanSepalWidth
         (chr)           (dbl)          (dbl)
1   groupbyvar        5.843333       3.057333
> 
> bb <- datafun("Species")
>
```

Any help is appreciated.  I have spent most of the day in futile attempts to make this work.  Nothing discovered that solved the problem,  Of course I could just copy, paste, search and replace but that is a last resort.  I am hopeful that creating meaningful variables from the data will reveal the confounder I suspect is hiding in the data.

Thanks
Carl Sutton

Comment: The error is because `groupbyvar` was not created.  `as.character(groupbyvar)` should understand what `groupbyvar` is.

Comment: How you create function without `{`? May be it is typo?  `datafun <- function(groupbyvar){
 groupbyvar <- as.character(groupbyvar) 
data(iris)
dtbl <- tbl_df(iris)
dtbl %>% group_by_(groupbyvar) %>%
  mutate(SpeciesArea = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width) %>%
  summarise(MeanSepalLenght = mean(Sepal.Length), MeanSepalWidth =
              mean(Sepal.Width))}

bb <- datafun("Species")`
 works for me

Comment: Is there an answer to post, I am still hunting around